# Questions about etiquette

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

There seems to be a growing number of questions about the "proper way to say/write ..." in the English SE.  I have also run across a few questions in Programmers SE that might be better suited for a general "manners" or "etiquette" SE.

Is it time to propose an Etiquette SE?

Comment: As @simchona says, there's an area51 slot. But I'm not sure EL&U should be looking to divert very much in that direction even if it gets up & running. There's not a lot of clear ground between *correct*, *acceptable*, and *polite* on many of these questions.

Answer (score 5):

There already is one. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29783/social-conventions-and-interaction

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have to go check that out.

Answer (score 5):

Ugh...I hate these kinds of questions...so easy to answer...but of little language value.

But then I think, really, they tend to have a component that is really about what the speech act means. And then I can see a benefit to this site.

So I think questions of these sorts are appropriate here at ELU as long as, just like with all questions, the primary component of the question is about the language.